# Flask and OpenCV don't support multiple people viewing the same camera

Tags: python, opencv, flask, camera

I have this code here

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)

def gen_frames():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(-1, cv2.CAP_V4L2)  
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=3884, debug=True)
```

The code works perfectly, until I try view it on 2 devices at once

If I try view it through 1 device only, it works fine, it accesses the camera fine.
But when I try to view the screen on another device while the 1st device is viewing,
it gives this error `[ WARN:8] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index`. I realize this is probably an error caused by the script trying to access the camera multiple times, but how can I fix this problem? Threads?

Comment: well yes, you have to figure out how to open that camera once, read from it, and distribute the frames to however many clients want the frames. that probably involves running the `camera.read()` in a thread and using `threading.Condition` objects. here's a recipe https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40

Comment: I noticed that if you try to access a camera from a website and an app at the same time, it just doesn't work because of security reasons I guess? So I'm not even sure that this is a code issue.